# Unable to recreate Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have created a project that is having HomeActivity (Navigation Drawer Activity) due to some reason I have deleted all file (layout java fragment and all files related to HomeActivity) and now trying to recreate it.

While I am creating new HomeActivity (Navigation Drawer Activity) it is not being created but I am getting error in my AndroidManifest.xml

below is the image of Manifest file -

[image]

steps used to create Navigation Drawer Activity-

Right-click on app > new > activity > navigation drawer activity, nothing happens! it just creates an XML file in menu directory.

Tried different name to create navigation drawer activity but getting the same error.

creating 2-time or recreating navigation drawer activity in all project cause the same error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First remove the `HomeActivity` tag from the manifest, and repeat the steps

Comment: already done. If delete it an create it is created again and no java or XML file is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to recreate a file you deleted, instead of going through all the hassle, if it is in your local history(under VCS at the top of android studio) you can just restore it if you deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the above error because some files related to the old activity you initially deleted are still in existence. So whenever you try to recreate the Navigation Activity the process is halted because some of the files needed to be created are already existing.

Answer (score 0):

First check that all files of activity are safely deleted including grade dependencies ,after that make sure you also delete XML files from drawable folder.
I posted solution too late but it may help others